# Copy selected answers from one case to another case SPSS

Tags: syntax, spss

I am having difficulty copying the responses from one case to another.

Example:
There are 3 siblings in a household. If a child shares a mother with one of the other siblings, questions pertaining to the mother are not asked to the 2nd child of that mother.

How do I then copy the answers from the mothers first child to the second child ? Illustration below

[image]

In household 1112 for example, since child 3 shares a mother with child 2 they were not asked about their mothers job or mothers age.

9998 reflects system missing data (question was skipped over)

How do I copy the responses for these variables to child 3?

Comment: Please edit your post to add a larger example of your actual SPSS data (a couple more households maybe?), this will make it easier to suggest a solution that will work in different (more complex) situations.

Comment: updated to add in more cases.

Comment: See my solution according to your updated post

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty weird way to record the data - is there no way to change this at the source? there should be a separate table for mothers' details, children table and mothers table connected through mother ID.
BUT - given the data in it's present form - here's what I thought of: the following code will create a copy of the original table and match it back up with itself while connecting between the number in the `child number` column and in the `bio_mother` column.

First I recreate some of your example data to demonstrate on:

```
data list list/HHID childnumber biomother mother_age (4f6) mother_job (a20).
begin data
    112 1   99998   25  "unemployed"
    112 2   0   33  "nurse"
    112 3   2   99998   "99998"
    116 1   99998   25  "domestic worker"
    116 2   1   99998   "99998"
    116 3   0   28  "sales assistant"
    116 4   3   99998   "99998"
end data.
dataset name orig.
```

Now to work:

```
dataset copy tab2.
dataset activate tab2.
delete vars biomother.
rename vars childnumber=biomother mother_age=Xmother_age mother_job=Xmother_job.
sort cases by HHID biomother .

dataset act orig.
sort cases by HHID biomother.
match files /file=* /tab=tab2/by HHID biomother .
exe.
```

Now we have the data in the right lines, last step is to copy it into the right columns.

```
if mother_age=99998 mother_age=Xmother_age.
if mother_job="99998" mother_job=Xmother_job.
exe.
```